# ArangoDB very slow aggregations

Tags: arangodb

i have a performance issue with aggregations in ArangoDB in a large collection (20 mln documents)

profile output:

```
Query String (169 chars, cacheable: false):
 FOR doc IN events
     FILTER doc.date > '2021-07-28T00:00:00'
     COLLECT type = doc.type WITH COUNT INTO cnt
     RETURN {
         "type": type,
         "cnt": cnt
     }

Execution plan:
 Id   NodeType          Calls     Items   Runtime [s]   Comment
  1   SingletonNode         1         1       0.00000   * ROOT
 10   IndexNode          1471   1470991       0.78432     - FOR doc IN events   /* persistent index scan, index only, projections: `type` */    
  5   CalculationNode    1471   1470991       0.34793       - LET #5 = doc.`type`   /* attribute expression */   /* collections used: doc : events */
  6   CollectNode           1        48       0.22653       - COLLECT type = #5 AGGREGATE cnt = LENGTH()   /* hash */
  9   SortNode              1        48       0.00005       - SORT type ASC   /* sorting strategy: standard */
  7   CalculationNode       1        48       0.00005       - LET #7 = { "type" : type, "cnt" : cnt }   /* simple expression */
  8   ReturnNode            1        48       0.00000       - RETURN #7

Indexes used:
 By   Name        Type         Collection   Unique   Sparse   Selectivity   Fields               Ranges
 10   date_type   persistent   events       false    false        40.11 %   [ `date`, `type` ]   (doc.`date` > "2021-07-28T00:00:00")

Optimization rules applied:
 Id   RuleName
  1   move-calculations-up
  2   move-filters-up
  3   move-calculations-up-2
  4   move-filters-up-2
  5   use-indexes
  6   remove-filter-covered-by-index
  7   remove-unnecessary-calculations-2
  8   move-calculations-down
  9   reduce-extraction-to-projection

Query Statistics:
 Writes Exec   Writes Ign   Scan Full   Scan Index   Filtered   Peak Mem [b]   Exec Time [s]
           0            0           0      1470991          0         196608         1.35927

Query Profile:
 Query Stage           Duration [s]
 initializing               0.00000
 parsing                    0.00004
 optimizing ast             0.00001
 loading collections        0.00001
 instantiating plan         0.00002
 optimizing plan            0.00029
 executing                  1.35889
 finalizing                 0.00003
```

there are 50 event.type and RETURN DISTINCT doc.type is also running slow

i tried to add an index on field type but things got even worse.

tried to create [type, date] and add SORT doc.type

```
Query String (187 chars, cacheable: false):
 FOR doc IN events
     SORT doc.type
     FILTER doc.date > '2021-07-28T00:00:00'
     COLLECT type = doc.type WITH COUNT INTO cnt
     RETURN {
         "type": type,
         "cnt": cnt
     }

Execution plan:
 Id   NodeType          Calls     Items   Runtime [s]   Comment
  1   SingletonNode         1         1       0.00000   * ROOT
 12   IndexNode          1471   1470991      17.29910     - FOR doc IN events   /* persistent index scan, index only, projections: `date`, `type` */    FILTER (doc.`date` > "2021-07-28T00:00:00")   /* early pruning */   
  3   CalculationNode    1471   1470991       0.36269       - LET #3 = doc.`type`   /* attribute expression */   /* collections used: doc : events */
  8   CollectNode           1        48       0.17226       - COLLECT type = #3 AGGREGATE cnt = LENGTH()   /* sorted */
  9   CalculationNode       1        48       0.00005       - LET #9 = { "type" : type, "cnt" : cnt }   /* simple expression */
 10   ReturnNode            1        48       0.00001       - RETURN #9

Indexes used:
 By   Name        Type         Collection   Unique   Sparse   Selectivity   Fields               Ranges
 12   type_date   persistent   events       false    false        39.97 %   [ `type`, `date` ]   *

Optimization rules applied:
 Id   RuleName
  1   move-calculations-up
  2   move-filters-up
  3   remove-redundant-calculations
  4   remove-unnecessary-calculations
  5   remove-redundant-sorts
  6   move-calculations-up-2
  7   use-indexes
  8   use-index-for-sort
  9   move-calculations-down
 10   reduce-extraction-to-projection
 11   move-filters-into-enumerate

Query Statistics:
 Writes Exec   Writes Ign   Scan Full   Scan Index   Filtered   Peak Mem [b]   Exec Time [s]
           0            0           0     21712260   20241269         327680        17.83480

Query Profile:
 Query Stage           Duration [s]
 initializing               0.00000
 parsing                    0.00004
 optimizing ast             0.00001
 loading collections        0.00001
 instantiating plan         0.00003
 optimizing plan            0.00034
 executing                 17.83435
 finalizing                 0.00003
```

is it possible to speed it up ?

Comment: Can you try with an index on `[type, date]` and add an explicit `SORT doc.type` before the `FILTER` and share the explain output?

Comment: @mpoeter thx for reply, it is slower than on [date, type], updated the description

Comment: Ok, unfortunately the execution engine isn't smart enough to recognize that it can use the index for the `FILTER` inside each type. Too bad, I can't think of anything else ATM.

Comment: it uses the FILTER, it returns 50 filtered docs in ~1ms , the issue appears only when i add COLLECT

Comment: I was referring to the second query where it uses the index for the sorting on type, but does not recognize that the index can also be used for filtering _within_ each type. Instead the filter is applied during early pruning, but we still walk the entire index.

Comment: Try removing your `SORT doc.type` and put in a `SORT null` after the `COLLECT` line.

I'm also assuming your server has enough RAM to hold the full collection in RAM, and then have spare RAM to do the calc?

Comment: @DavidThomas nothing changed , yes ram is enough - but it doesnt use it , info shows Estimated documents size: 3.13 GB and Estimated size of indexes:  
1.12 GB but it uses currently only 566 MiB